# helping getting started with audio programming languages

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I have a small application I have been working on for some time to help my son with his speech delay. I am using `gstreamer` to play phonemes, small audio clips about 100ms long.

Things are fine but I find it a bit distasteful to use a library that has such powerful video features for an audio only application.

I was thinking that an audio programing language might be able to play short audio clips on-the-fly too.

I've been reading about these DSLs and there are quite a few of them. However it seems that [`csound`](http://www.csounds.com/), [`Supercollider`](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/) and [`Chuck`](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/) are the *front runners*.

All I really need to do right now is to play small audio clips, preferably from a `C` binding, in near real time and I only need to run on Linux.

Could anyone help me pick a language for this? There are so many features I *"can't see the forest for the trees"*.

Once I have one picked out, I will have a tool for my immediate needs and a platform to grow with as my needs change.

Comment: I will try to help, but I think you need to make your question a little more specific or it *risks* being closed.  You can always just use `aplay` and a `shell` script to play different phonemes.  [ChildsPlay](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/learning-childsplay) is a game like program written in Python and has some letters/sounds.  Also, programs like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) maybe helpful.  Telling more about where you are trying to go would be helpful.

Comment: Also useful may be [CMU's speech page](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/).  These are pages for speech recognitions and generation.  You can run modes where you just output *phonemes* only in *flite* and others.

Answer (score 2):

SuperCollider has great real-time capabilities and makes it pretty easy to play sound files via its sclang interpreter. It's also not that hard to communicate with the supercollider server (scsynth, the part of supercollider that actually synthesize sounds) via open sound control (OSC) messages, so you can control the synth from another, separate application.

Don't know much about chuck but I hear it's good for on-the-fly, live audio programming too so it might work.

I wouldn't recommand CSound since it's meant to be used for composition, more like a "compiled" language vs interpreted. You basically write a score file and generate a whole sound file from that, so it's probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I will start reading about supercollider clients